how to create Sankey chart in Tableau with 3 data in 3 different table
I need assistance in creating a Sankey chart in Tableau. The challenge is that the data for the three columns I want to use comes from different tables, and they are connected through data blending. I've searched on Google and YouTube, and they suggest unioning the tables with themselves, but since I have three distinct tables, I'm unsure how to proceed. Do you have any ideas or links that could help resolve this issue?

Sankeys are a bit tricky even with simple data. If you want more feedback, show some sample data, what you're trying and what results you see. And I'd separate in your mind the two very different tasks of creating the correct values and presenting the values graphically. First make sure you can just display the values you want in a table or simple bar chart, and once you have the values correct, learn how to present them visually as you desire. Two different tasks

Tableau 2024.2 will have Sankey feature
